# Fastest cheap way to get from Morocco to Algeria?

Tags: public-transport, budget, overland, morocco, algeria

Some friends and I want to go from Fez, Morocco, to Algiers over a long weekend, but flying from Casablanca ($350) is above our willingness to pay.

What's the fastest way, cheaper than flying from Casablanca, to get from Fez, Morocco, to Algiers, Algeria?

Comment: I am afraid that flying is the best option... By car, train or bus, it will take a lot of time to get there without talking about the security aspect... Then, you can probably find better rates by comparing and planning in advance.

Comment: The almighty [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/F%C3%A8s/Algiers) doesn't find anything either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best cheaper way I've found to get from Fez to Algiers is **flying via Barcelona**.

As of April 2016, Fez - Barcelona - Fez is around $35-50 on Ryanair, and Barcelona - Algiers - Barcelona is around $110 on Vueling, for a total price of $150 (round trip).